# How to compare content between two web pages in different environments?

Tags: testing, sitecore

We are in the process of building a website from scratch from an existing website. The web page is an identical copy, and as the web page contains many pages we need a way to compare content between the sites. It is of course possible to do manually, but it takes both a lot of time and entails a risk of human errors.

I have seen that there are services that offer this by inputting two URLs which are then analyzed and where discrepancies are presented. However, these cannot be used as our test environment is local (built in Sitecore).

Is there a way to solve this without making our test environment available online (which is not possible)? For example, does software exist for this, or alternatively some service where you can compare a web page that is online with one that is local?

Note that we're only looking for content comparison (not visual).

Answer (score 0):

(Un)fortunately there's many ways to do this, but fortunately there are some simple ones.
What I would do is:

1. Get a list of URLs for each site. If the Sitemap is exhaustive, then you could use that, if it's not you might want to run some Sitecore Powershell to get the lists.
2. Given the lists (from files, or Sitecore API or something), write a program to visit each URL, get the text of the page after it's done rendering, and save it to disk (something like Selenium is good for this and you can use any language). You'll want some folder structure like `host/urlpart/urlpart/pagename.txt`, basically the same as your content tree.
3. Use some filesystem diff program like WinMerge to compare the two folders

This is quick and dirty, but a good place to start.